# Simple Page Redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a page at http://site.com/services/ and I just want to redirect it to http://site.com/servics/first-service/

Whats the best redirect to do this and how do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PHP**:

```php
header("Location: yourpage.php");
exit;
```

You have to use `exit` or `die` after `header` in order to stop execution of your code.
Also, the code has to be executed before any output.

---

**HTML**:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=yourpage.php">
```

The code should be placed between `<head></head>` tags.

---

**JavaScript**:

```
window.location = "yourpage.php";
```

---

**.htaccess**:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.php /newpage.php
```

Comment: what's the essence of the exit?

Comment: `exit()` or `die()` - if you not use one of them, rest of your code will continue executing after redirection is done.

Comment: I have not noticed that before. I will do some test to confirm that. Thanks.

Comment: First piece of code will redirect any page to `yourpage.php` not only those found on `/services` path and the second one relies on JavaScript and is considered highly undesirable because web crawlers do tend to consider client side induced refreshes as malicious.

Comment: @holodoc: ofc `header` will redirect any page. Why would someone put it on a page that shouldn't be redirected from? Put it on a page what you want to redirect users from.

Comment: Because `/services` path might only be part of the whole website and only requests that actually contain `/services` should be redirected. Not only that but if you explicitly set a redirection target like this you will be destroying potential form (GET, POST) data that **will not** be carried over to the redirected page. Considering that his path (folder) is named `services` this would be particularly dangerous as the name itself suggests that at least some kind of form data is sent. That's the reason why `mod_rewrite` or simple redirects are used in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a simple [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive.

```
Redirect /services /services/first-service
```

You can choose what kind of a response code you will send to the client. Further info on that on the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a permanent change, you want to use a 301 redirect google has some [good content on the matter](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105)

To build the redirect just add

```
redirect 301 /services/  http://site.com/services/first-service/
```

to .htacess on the top level of your directory tree.  **NOTE I switched 'servcs' from your example to services**

Answer (score 0):

in javascript: `window.location = "/first-service";`

Answer (score 0):

I use this as an Index file in the folder's that I don't want the public to brows,,,,

```
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow" />

<?php

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];            // Get the server//

header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301);              // Use either 301 or 302//

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried javascript `window.location = "http://site.com/servics/first-service/";` ? I hope it works.

Comment: **-1**: `window.location` is not a function.

Comment: window.location is a function when you open your script tags and have your javascript ready ! Use google for simple stuff like this  [link](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

Comment: No, it's not a function. `location` the a property of the `window` object. [Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp). `window.location('')` is incorrect. The correct is `window.location = ''`