# redirecting from one site to another

Tags: php, html, redirect

Is there any way to redirect every pages on a website to another website ?

Actually what I mean is that, I own two websites eg :

1. 1.com
2. 2.com

2.com is my main website. When I add a page to 2.com (eg:2.com/index.html), 1.com ignores it and creates (1.com/index.html) with the redirecting code to 2.com/index.html.
Can I do this ?

Is there any way to do this by php ?

Actually what I need is a script that automatically create files which are added to my 2nd site on my 1st site. So Can I do this with php and mysql or any other scripting or programming language?

Comment: Are you saying that you want two sites that are identical and can be accessed via separate domain names?

Comment: Are you talking about _static_ or _dynamic_ file ?

Comment: @jtlebi I have edited my answer based on this information. You can do this by altering the DNS records of 1.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you own both domains you could just both redirect them to your website using a DNS-A-record or whatever and then simply use a server alias (`Server Alias`) as outlined [on apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/de/mod/core.html#ServerAlias). If the user then visits the domain, he will still see the original domain, which he visited.

Another way would be using a rewrite rule as described by [this blog](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.2.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then your users would always see 1.com in their address bar.

Answer (score 2):

// Put this script on 1.com and it will redirect to to 2.com or vice versa

```
<?php

header('Location: http://2.com/index.html');
exit();

?>
```

If I did not understand your question correctly, let me know and I will help you as best I can.

// Super hack time

```
<?php
// 1.com
$files = scandir('./*'); // not recursive, note that
$sent = file($files['log.txt']);
unset($files['log.txt']);
$notsent = array_diff($files, $sent);
foreach($notsent as $file) {
     $contents = file_get_contents($file);
     // Use curl to post to 2.com receiving script http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl
     file_put_contents($sent, $file, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Disclaimer: Have not tested, but it is the most direct way to do what I *think* you want. Again I really don't know why you would want to do this.

Comment: is there script which can automatically create 1.com/index.html when i add 2.com/index.html which contain your code?

Comment: actually I want to create a file 1.com/index.html automatically by running a script while index.html is added to 2.com

Comment: Okay-- check my answer for updates, but this highly NOT RECOMMENDED for security and practicality reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to do with PHP, since a PHP code is executed when file is launched, and not when *any* file on server is launched.
Possible with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Redirecting to www.newdomain.com from every page on your old domain.

---

*See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441146/simple-page-redirect/11441186#11441186) for more methods about redirecting.*

Answer (score 1):

The above answer can only be used before any html has been loaded. If you're looking for something that is easier to implement use this:

```
<script>window.location = 'http://google.com';</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not sure if I completely understood your question.*

**With PHP**

```
header('Location: http://2.com');
```

**With HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://2.com">
```

**Having provided more information:**

Add a CNAME record to the DNS of 1.com with the value of 2.com

Comment: CNAME will only deal with the host. If there is some virtual host logic (as in moste web servers), then you need to add 1.com as an alias of 2.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to setup Nginx web server on 1.com and configure it as a proxy, so 2.com actually handles all requests. Thus you can avoid replicating the whole 2.com on 1.com and at the same time the user browser will not be redirected to 1.com like if you use *Location* header.