# Call redirect PHP Function

Tags: php, function, redirect, call

Im trying to make a simple php redirect file that will work like this on browser:

```
File.php?redirect_url=http://www.example.com
```

It should redirect to any website written in redirect_url=WEBSITE
I dont know how File.php should be like.

```
if(function_exists($_GET['redirect_url'])) {
$_GET['redirect_url']();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Page Redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441146/simple-page-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
header("location:$_GET['redirect_url']");
```

Comment: This one seems easier! Thanks it worked, had to write [redirect_url] without  '

Answer (score 2):

your code should be like-

```
 if(isset($_GET['redirect_url'])){
    $redirect=$_GET['redirect_url'];

        header("LOCATION:".$redirect);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any function to achieve just what you are trying to do.

```
if (isset($_GET['redirect_url'])) {
    header("Location: $_GET[redirect_url]");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! had to use [redirect_url] without '